# Golang fileserver throws not found

Tags: go

I am trying to serve some fonts, but when i visit localhost:4000/fonts, it gives me 404 not found. my code:

```
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./fonts"))

    http.Handle("/fonts", http.StripPrefix("/fonts/", fs))

    http.Handle("/", app.routes())

    log.Println("Serving at localhost:4000...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%d", cfg.Port), nil))
```

UPDATE

if im serving from "/" and not "/fonts", it works. but i want it to work from "/fonts".

Comment: i cant believe im the only one in the world encountering this problem, since no answers XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not strip the trailing slash after fonts since you want the result to be */file* and not *file*.

You should also add the trailing slash to the handler path, for the same reason.

```golang
http.Handle("/fonts/", http.StripPrefix("/fonts", fs))
```

Both changes, as mentioned, have the purpose to leave you with a path like `/somefile` that is looked up against the filesevers file system.